# Custom Authentication Provider Not Being Called

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm trying to setup a customer AuthenticationProvider with Spring Security but not having much luck getting it working.  I'm using **Java configuration** so I'm probably missing something simple but as most the learning material is XML config based, it's not jumping out at me.

This is using Spring v4.0.1.RELEASE but with Spring Security v3.2.2.RELEASE.  Version number clash perhaps?

As far as I could tell, all I had to do was create my provider:

```
public class KBServicesAuthProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {
  @Autowired
  private ApplicationConfig applicationConfig;

  @Autowired
  private SessionServiceClient sessionServiceClient;

  @Override
  public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
    String email = (String) authentication.getPrincipal();
    String password = (String) authentication.getCredentials();

    try {
      KBSessionInfo sessionInfo = sessionServiceClient.login(applicationConfig.getKbServicesPresenceId(), email,
          password);

      List<GrantedAuthority> grantedRoles = new ArrayList<>();
      for (KBRoleMembership role : sessionInfo.getAuthenticatedUser().getRoleMemberships()) {
        grantedRoles.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getRoleId()));
      }

      return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(email, password, grantedRoles);
    } catch (InvalidSessionException e) {
      throw new AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException("Username or password was not accepted", e);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
    return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
  }
}
```

And then setup a class to describe my security setup. This class links in my provider:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Autowired(required = true)
  SessionServiceClient sessionServiceClient;

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();
    http.formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll().and().logout().permitAll();
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(getKBServicesAuthenticationProvider());
  }

  @Bean
  protected AuthenticationProvider getKBServicesAuthenticationProvider() {
    return new KBServicesAuthProvider();
  }
}
```

But I'm not seeing anything in the logs & none of my debug points are being hit.  The app acts as it's unsecured (so I can reach various URLs etc. still).

Any ideas on what I should be checking?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This might not be the complete answer, as I'm struggling with this a bit myself.  I'm using a custom authentication provider and a custom user details service.  I see the same behavior as you -- breakpoints get hit in my user details service, but not in my authentication provider.  Here is what my entire config class looks like:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        AuthenticationProvider rememberMeAuthenticationProvider = rememberMeAuthenticationProvider();
        TokenBasedRememberMeServices tokenBasedRememberMeServices = tokenBasedRememberMeServices();

        List<AuthenticationProvider> authenticationProviders = new ArrayList<AuthenticationProvider>(2);
        authenticationProviders.add(rememberMeAuthenticationProvider);
        authenticationProviders.add(customAuthenticationProvider);
        AuthenticationManager authenticationManager = authenticationManager(authenticationProviders);

        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .headers().disable()
                .addFilter(new RememberMeAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager, tokenBasedRememberMeServices))
                .rememberMe().rememberMeServices(tokenBasedRememberMeServices)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/js/**", "/css/**", "/img/**", "/login", "/processLogin").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/index.jsp", "/index.html", "/index").hasRole("USER")
                .antMatchers("/admin", "/admin.html", "/admin.jsp", "/js/saic/jswe/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .and()
                .formLogin().loginProcessingUrl("/processLogin").loginPage("/login").usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password").permitAll()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/login")
                .and()
                .logout().permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/js/**", "/css/**", "/img/**");
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(List<AuthenticationProvider> authenticationProviders) {
        return new ProviderManager(authenticationProviders);
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenBasedRememberMeServices tokenBasedRememberMeServices() {
        return new TokenBasedRememberMeServices("testKey", userDetailsService);
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider rememberMeAuthenticationProvider() {
        return new org.springframework.security.authentication.RememberMeAuthenticationProvider("testKey");
    }

    protected void registerAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }
}
```

I've just discovered that if I specifically add my authentication provider to the HttpSecurity object, my breakpoints start getting hit:

```
http
                .csrf().disable()
                .headers().disable()
                .authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider)
```

My goal is to get a BCryptPasswordEncoder working, which does not with this config -- everything returns as bad credentials.  Anyway, just thought I'd share.

Comment: Always nice to know you're not the only one struggling! I'll give this a go when I'm back at work tomorrow & let you know how if I make progress

Comment: I hope it does for you.  This let me get my password encoder working properly as well, however now I think I broke my rememberMe services!

Comment: Still haven't got this to work but at least you've given me a complete example to go from!

Comment: Even tho it's maybe WAAAAY to late, I think you're missing this:
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)

Comment: And as for Bal, you can add more than one Authentication Provider to your configure Method:
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth

        .authenticationProvider(new CustomAuthenticationProvider())  
        .userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
  }

Answer (score 9):

### Use `isAssignableFrom()` instead of `==` or `equals`.

The problem is with the `supports()` method which will always return false.

Change from:

```
@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
      return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
}
```

---

To:

#### Java

```
@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
    return (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication));
}
```

#### Kotlin

```
override fun supports(authentication: Class<*>): Boolean {
    return UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken::class.java.isAssignableFrom(authentication)
}
```

Finally the flow would pass through `authenticate()`

Answer (score 3):

I had same issue (my custom auth provider is not hit) and solved the issue by introducing **springSecurityFilterChain**, after reading [Why is Spring Security working in Tomcat but not when deployed to Weblogic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29392595/why-is-spring-security-working-in-tomcat-but-not-when-deployed-to-weblogic)
So my problem was maybe tied specifically with WebServer, but I had the custom auth provider issue also on Tomcat and checked my configuration works now on Tomcat.

I'm using spring boot 1.4.1 version which contains Spring 4.3.3 and Spring Security 4.1.3 and following [Traditional deployment](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html)

I tested my configuration against *Tomcat v9.0* and also *WebLogic 12c R2* and checked it worked on both.
hope this helpful at least to someone using Tomcat.

Below is my configuration started from main class.

**Application.java**

```
public class Application {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        SpringApplication.run(new Class[] {AppConfig.class, Initializer.class, SecurityInitializer.class}, args);
    }
}
```

**Initializer.java**

```
public class Initializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(AppConfig.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        rootContext.register(AppConfig.class);

        // Manage the lifecycle of the root application context
        container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

        // Create the dispatcher servlet's Spring application context
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        dispatcherContext.register(WebConfig.class);

        // Register and map the dispatcher servlet
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = container.addServlet("my-servlet", new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherContext));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/*");
    }
}
```

Here the AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer is building the *springSecurityFilterChain* from onStartup method. I didn't implement any, since I'm trying to use default configuration.

**SecurityInitializer.java**

```
public class SecurityInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

}
```

**AppConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableScheduling
@EnableMBeanExport
@EnableAsync
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@ComponentScan("com.my.package")
public class AppConfig {


}
```

**SecurityConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan("com.my.package")
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private RestfulRemoteAuthenticationProvider restfulRemoteAuthenticationProvider;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(restfulRemoteAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().httpBasic();
    }
}
```

**WebConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.my.controller.package")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver internalViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        viewResolver.setOrder(1);
        return viewResolver;
    }
}
```

This is my custom auth provider to get authentication info from other component via Restful request

**RestfulRemoteAuthenticationProvider.java**

```
@Component
public class RestfulRemoteAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Autowired
    private ManagementClientAdapterFactory managementClientAdapterFactory;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        String username = authentication.getName();
        String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

        // my logic to get and configure authSource which is my environment specific thing, also same for RemoteAuthRequestResult

        RemoteAuthRequestResult result = (RemoteAuthRequestResult)authSource.sendRequest();
        if(result.isAuthenticated()) {
            List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuths = new ArrayList<>();
            grantedAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password, grantedAuths);
        }
        throw new BadCredentialsException("User not found by given credential");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   Something like should be present in java config 
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)
public class HelloMethodSecurityConfig {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the `@Autowired` annotation.

```
@Autowired
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
  auth.authenticationProvider(getKBServicesAuthenticationProvider());
}
```

Also, you may want to remove the `.antMatchers("/").permitAll()`.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
  http.formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll().and().logout().permitAll();
}
```

Comment: I added the @AutoWired annotation but still no luck. With or without the annotation that configure method does get called so something is going on. But the authentication provider I am setting up never has any of it's method called.

Comment: Did you also remove the `.antMatchers("/").permitAll()`?

Comment: There is no need to add an @Autowired annotation to this method because it is called from the super class which provides the parameter.

Answer (score 1):

`@EnableWebMvcSecurity` will be deprecated in 4.0 https://jira.spring.io/browse/SEC-2790

You might want to re consider you configuration.

Answer (score 0):

```
<security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>
```

Comment: I'm not using the XML configuration, I'm using Java config instead.  I'll see if there's an alternative in that though.

Comment: @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)  although i don't think this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and this was because I used @Autowire-ed `AuthenticationManager` instance, that was built by spring boot and simply not contained my custom `AuthenticationProvider`.

After two days of debugging of spring guts I finally realize that this is not same instance, as manager from `org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter#authenticationManager()` which I configured in my custom `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` through `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter#configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder)`.

Now I simply get this instance from `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter#authenticationManager()` and pass it to my `GenericFilterBean`, which is handle my auth logic. Works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Also, make sure you are sending the user and password with correct headers.

Test curl below, and check the class is been invoked

```
curl -X GET \
  http://localhost:8080  \
  -H 'Authorization: Basic cmdlbGxtYW5AYnIuaWJtLmNvbTphYmM=' \
  -H 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache'
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was that I needed to disable CSRF, since I'm using API, not HTML pages:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable();
}
```

Comment: You don't *disable* CSRF, it is a security vulnerability. What do you mean "disable"?

Comment: @Someone_who_likes_SE CSRF is useful for HTML pages, not APIs.