# Spring security - Custom AuthenticationProvider not working - Java Config

Tags: java, spring, security, authentication, spring-security

I'm struggling with the problem from the title for few days already and I'm pretty frustrated. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong and why my implementation isn't working.

Let me show you what I've got:

Custom AuthenticationProvider:

```
@Component
public class AuthProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthProvider.class);

    public AuthProvider() {
        logger.info("Building...");
    }

    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        logger.info("Authenticate...");
        return null;
    }

    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        logger.info("Supports...");
        return true;
    }
}
```

WebSecurity config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthProvider authProvider;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
}
```

As you can see I've added loggers into the AuthenticationProvider but not any of them is getting called.

What I've tried:

- adding `@Autowired` to `configure` where the `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` is
- adding `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)` to the class
- adding custom `AuthenticationProvider` directly to `HttpSecurity`

How I've tested it:

- debugging via IntelliJ - no results, no breakpoint is getting called.
- running the app and sending a request - also no results, no logs, nothing.

Please guys help me somehow. I'm outta energy. I hate wasting so much time on things that should just work :(

Comment: @dur Is this information necessary in case of this problem? I don't have any authentication right now, that's why I wanted to create my own AuthProvider. I'm planning to authenticate JWT.

Comment: @dur 403 Forbidden.

Comment: @dur `http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();` isn't making it to authenticate all requests? I think that I don't understand it properly :D

Comment: That's the reason, why you get a 403. If you use `permitAll` you will get a 200 with anonymous user, too. Before you write your own `AuthenticationProvider`, you should learn the core concepts of Spring Security, please read [Spring Security Reference](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.1.x/reference/htmlsingle/).

Comment: That sounds reasonable. Thanks anyways for pointing this out and sorry for taking Your time! I thought that I understand this properly :)

Comment: You return null from the authenticate() method, - this is the reason. It should return a real Authentication object (for example, an instance of UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken or its subclass).

Comment: @dur, can you please explain whats the issue in this code. i am facing the same problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably you missed the following method in your WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter:

```
@Bean
@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}
```

The same happened to me.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `isAssignableFrom()` method instead of instead of `==` or `equals` we get a true, then the flow would pass through `authenticate()`

```
override fun supports(authentication: Class<*>): Boolean {
    return UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken::class.java.isAssignableFrom(authentication)
}
```

GL

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44650177/5279996)